# Generic constructor

Tags: java, generics, constructor

Let we have the following class:

```
public class MyClass<T>{
    public <E> MyClass(E e){ System.out.println(e.toString);}
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MyClass(new String("string"));//will be invoked comstructor MyClass(Object)
    }
}
```

As known when we create a new instance of class firstly invoked a method of this class who called constructor. **Questions:**

1. Is it true that by default type of constructor's return value is `void`?
2. Does from type erasure following that constructor `public <E> MyClass(E e){ System.out.println(e.toString);}` equivalent to `public MyClass(Object o){ System.out.println(o.toString);}`?

Comment: Constructors can never return anything.

Comment: @St.Antario: The thing you are defining is not a constructor. It's just another method.

Comment: @EnnoShioji. How? It's a generic constructor.

Comment: the `E` here is completely unnecessary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it true that by default type of constructor's return value is void?

You don't give any explicit return type to a constructor. However, a constructor is internally converted to a `non-static` method named `<init>` whose return type is `void`.

From [JVM Spec Section 2.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9):

> At the level of the Java Virtual Machine, every `constructor` written in the Java programming language (JLS §8.8) appears as an *instance initialization method* that has the special name `<init>`. This name is supplied by a compiler. Because the name `<init>` is not a valid *identifier*, it cannot be used directly in a program written in the Java programming language. *Instance initialization methods* may be invoked only within the Java Virtual Machine by the `invokespecial` instruction (§invokespecial), and they may be invoked only on uninitialized class instances. An instance initialization method takes on the access permissions (JLS §6.6) of the constructor from which it was derived.

Similarly, the *static initializers* are internally converted to a `static` method - `<clinit>`, again with return type `void`.

> Does from type erasure following that constructor `public <E> MyClass(E e){ System.out.println(e.toString);}` equivalent to `public MyClass(Object o){ System.out.println(o.toString);}`?

Yes. The erasure of a type parameter is its leftmost bound. In this case, since there is no bound to `E`, the erasure is `Object`.

Had you declared your constructor as:

```
public <E extends Integer> MyClass(E e){ System.out.println(e.toString);}
```

the erasure of this would be:

```
public MyClass(Integer e){ System.out.println(e.toString);}
```

As the leftmost bound of `E` is now an `Integer`.

---

**References:**

- [Oracle Tutorial - Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)
- [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is type erasure?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20erasure?)
  - [What is type erasure of a type parameter?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ108)

Comment: @Bohemian Please feel free to add anything that I might have missed. Thanks :)

Comment: _However, a constructor is internally converted to a non-static method named <init> whose return type is void._ Where this converstion is invoking? In this case `new MyClass(new String("string"));` at compile time compiler checked for existence of constructor and just after this compiler coverted constructor to `<init>`. Is it true?

Comment: @St.Antario. When the class is compiled, at that time only compiler creates the `<init>` method for the constructor.

Comment: (already +1) looks pretty good :) encyclopaedic, as always. Nice job.